# error when update-database in backage manager consol

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-core

when I update-database in backage manager console it gives me this error

The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: The term 'dotnet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

it is 2 days till now and I didn't find any solution , could you help me on this ?vi

Comment: Could you update the question with the command you are using to update the database?

Comment: the command is update-database

Comment: I faced some issues before when I was trying to use `Update-Database` command, and one of the issues is that I forgot to add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` package. And the other one is I just  closed visual studio and reopen it again. If you are windows user, open **command line** and Switch to the location of your project and try `dotnet ef database update`

Comment: thank you my problem solved I downloaded asp.net core sdk component and the problem solved now

Comment: I also faced this problem for `add-migration` i have just uninstalled the un used sdks. i am working on it now.